All shortcut desktop icons are blank
I'm using W11 and all my desktop icons are blank. The taskbar icons show perfectly.  Manually changing the desktop icons temporarily shows the icons as changed in the folder,  but upon closing the folder, it doesn't save it. I have done all the recommended lists of deleting the cache, etc.

Reboot your machete before running any commands

Do you mean the icons are white page icons instead of the images they are supposed to be, or something else?

I already ran dism/sfc, etc.  The icons are white page icons instead of the images they are supposed to be. However the taskbar icons are ok.

@Ramhound ... a machete seems a little extreme dosen't it?

@Jimjrre a screenshot might be helpful in letting people see what it actually looks for you, and might jog some memories

I tried to paste a screenshot into comments. The desktop icons are blank but not the taskbar icons.  And if I try to modify the desktop icons, it will temporarily save it in the folder, but when I close the folder, it did not really save it.  It will open just like it was before.  This happened after a windows update.   "Is there a way to change the registry to make sure these are really being saved?"

@Ramhound, do you mean to kill processes that way? Such a tool is only needed for a cutting-edge developer.

@DrMoishePippik - I have solved many desktop issues by simply rebooting only to discover a pending update was pending to be installed.

@Ramhound, The reference was to the machete in you comment -- I thought that was overkill ;-)

By "Ian Xue" from MS page;

Open Command Prompt as administrator from the start menu.


Run "taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe" to stop explorer.
Run "del %localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\iconcache*" to
delete the icon cache files.
Run "start explorer.exe" to start explorer and the icon cache should be rebuilt automatically.

Original link.

Ran suggestions from Ian Xue. No effect.

@John - Because you decided to delete it. It goes without saying, doing a repair install, isn't the solution to every problem.

@Jimjrre, did you try to make a new user acc, and how icons behave there?
